# Mysql table named with 2 numbers

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

So i have a table named "30" and a table named "kev"

When i query to the table named "30" i get

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in # on line 94
```

When i do the same to kev i do get the result i was asking for.

This is my script :

```
<?php 
$q1 = "SELECT * FROM '.$user.' ORDER BY `ID` DESC";
$r1 = $db1->query($q1);
foreach ($r1 as $row){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['ID'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Title'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Sub'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use back ticks around the table name.

Example:

```
`30`
```

Change:

```
"SELECT * FROM '.$user.' ORDER BY `ID` DESC";
```

To:

```
"SELECT * FROM `$user` ORDER BY `ID` DESC";
```

Comment: Did it. I'm still getting the same error.

// Edit. Fixed it! removed the 2 . between $user.

Comment: It alerted me too. Edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"SELECT * FROM `$user` ORDER BY `ID` DESC";
```